# how to set a sectionNameKeyPath for an NSFetchedResultsController for day's without using transient properties

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController to display messages in a tableView.

The messages are grouped into sections by date.  Presently date is a computed transient property.

```
extension Message {

    @objc public var messageDateSectionIdentifier: String? {
        var dateString = ""
        self.willAccessValue(forKey: "messageDateSectionIdentifier")
        if let date = self.messageDateCreated {
            let calendar = Formatters.calendar
            let today = Date()
            let yesterday = today.addingTimeInterval(-86400.0)
            if calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: today) {
                dateString = LocalizedStrings.DateStrings.Today
            } else if calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: yesterday) {
                dateString = LocalizedStrings.DateStrings.Yesterday
            } else {
                dateString = Formatters.messageDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            }
        }
        self.didAccessValue(forKey: "messageDateSectionIdentifier")

        return dateString
    }

}
```

And the initialization of the NSFetchedResultsController:

```
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "messageDateSectionIdentifier", cacheName: "root")
```

Everything works fine with the fetchedResultsController using the transient computed property as the sectionNameKeyPath, however this means that the fetchBatchSize is useless as the fetchedResultsController loads all data in loops of batchSize.  This is confirmed using instruments CoreData.  If I set nil for the sectionNameKeyPath or set it to a non-transient, the fetchBatchSize works and only the first batch is loaded.  However with the transient property, all batches are loaded initially.

The only solution to this is not using a transient property for the sectionNameKeyPath.  Is there any other way to arrange the sectionNameKeyPath by date from the timestamp on the message without the use  of a transient property?

I don't want to store an additional date property of the message because the user can change timezones.

Comment: You could use a time stamp property and update it for all records when you detect a timezone change (this is is probably a reasonably rare event and wouldn't take very long, even for tens of thousands of records) or you can not use a fetchred results controller and just fetch records in batches ordered by the existing (presumably UTC) time stamp, calculating local time as you go.